# Configure Firefox to allow no more than 10 tabs/windows

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, browser-tabs

How do I configure Firefox so that the user should not or can not open more then 10 tabs/windows during a session?

Or is there an add-on that will do this?

Comment: i so need this as well. 215 tabs open means i need to do some pruning

Answer (score 5):

Install the [Window and Tab Limiter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9129/) addon.